# How can I group images with dates like gallery

Tags: android-recyclerview, image-gallery, android-gallery, photo-gallery

I m making a gallery app, where I want to group images with dates and also want to  show a date above group of images that belong to that date. Like Google photos app

Any suggestions ????

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a logical grouping by keeping the date of when the user uploaded the image and in the gallery page, group the images by the creation date or the week or month of creation date and draw some thumbnails  for the dates, and when the user clicks on the thumbnail, retrieve all photos that has a creation date that falls in the selected date.
ex: if you grouped the photos using the week, this means when you open an album, you will get all the photos with creation date > week start day and creation date < ween end day